# OnClick Listener to apply to the whole card view instead of just the textView

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement the onclick on the cardview in a recycler view. Currently I can only set the textview in a cardview to be clickable, like my code shows:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShopViewHolder shopViewHolder, final int i) {
    shopViewHolder.shopNameTV.setText(shops.get(i).name);
    shopViewHolder.categoryTV.setText(shops.get(i).category);
    shopViewHolder.phoneNumberTV.setText(shops.get(i).phoneNumber);
    shopViewHolder.ratingsTV.setText(shops.get(i).ratings);
    shopViewHolder.emailTV.setText(shops.get(i).email);

    final Shop shop = shops.get(i);
    shopViewHolder.shopNameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("test", "onclickk here" + i);
 //           Intent intent = new Intent(RVAdapter.this,CustomerGetQueueActivity.class);
        }
    }) ;
}
```

Right now I can only set the shopNameTV to be clickable but I want the whole card to be clickable. When I tried to use shopViewHolder.setOnClickListener it shows me an error saying "cannot resolve method setOnClickListener(anonymous.android.view.View.OnClickListener).

How can I set the whole card to be clickable instead of just the textview inside the card ?

Comment: set click listener in your itemview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is, applying the onClickListeners only to specific fields. That's why it is not applicable to whole view. You are almost there, all you need to do is.

```
shopViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("test", "onclickk here" + i);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(RVAdapter.this,CustomerGetQueueActivity.class); 
    } 
}) ;
```

> public final View itemView

It is the parent view of your RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

**EDIT**

To resolve new problem, mentioned in comments:-

You will need to pass Application or component context as a first parameter to the Intent Constructor when you are creating an Intent for a specific component of your application.

Step 1 : Pass context to the constructor of Adapter

```
public class RVAdapter extend BaseAdapter{
Context mContext;
public RVAdapter(Context context, ... ) //Other parameters
{
mContext = context;
//Other code
}
```

Step 2 : Now use this context to start new Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CustomerGetQueueActivity.class);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help I kinda figured it out. Right now I have another problem whereby when I click on the cards, i want it to intent to another class, but when I insert the code like Intent intent = new Intent(RVAdapter.this,CustomerGetQueueActivity.class); there is another error where it says cannot resolve constructor. How do I solve this error ?

Comment: You will need to pass Application or component context as a first parameter to the Intent Constructor when you are creating an Intent for a specific component of your application.

So the best option you have is to pass context to the RVAdapter, and then use it as 

`new Intent(mContext, CustomerGetQueueActivity.class);`

I guess now i deserve a upvote and accepted answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Save the `view` that is passed to your `ShopViewHolder` as a member variable name it for example `cardView`.

then use below code inside your `onBindViewHolder`:

```
shopViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
}) ;
```